# icon set/library for angular 2 and above

Tags: angular

I used Ionic and it provides default [ionicons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/) icon set. I'm new to angular. I'm searching for angular icon set.

What is the default icon set for the angular app?

I know, it is a basic question but yet not finding any official link, what is default icon set or any preferred one?

Please guide me!

Comment: like [font awesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)?

Comment: yes.. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a preferred Angular icon set. Some standard ones that you'll see being used often are [Bootstrap's Glyphicons](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp) and [Material Design's icons](https://material.io/icons/). However, Angular itself is entirely agnostic and makes no special preference for any type of icon at all.